# Writing a dictionary to a csv file with 'key: value' on separate rows

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've got a dictionary:

```
mydict = {id: num, cityid: loc, days: tem}
```

My original sample.csv looks like this:

```
id, cityid, days
1,45,78
3,67,79
6,76,86
```

I want to write the data to a file sample.csv, in this style:

```
id, cityid, days 
num, loc, tem
1,45,78
3,67,79
6,76,86
```

Comment: You want to insert a row underneath the header?

Comment: yes and then write the values of dictionary on the second line

Comment: You just want to insert a new line in your csv file, why do you need to parse and rewrite the file as csv at all? You can do this as a simple text file edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example reading a file 'test.csv' in your working directory. The keys of mydict must equal the first row of your csv.

1 - Read CSV file and put the information in list *rows*

```
import csv

filename = 'test.csv'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)
```

2 - Create dictionary *mydict* for header (NOTE FIRST ROW OF CSV MUST CONTAIN THE KEYS OF *mydict*

```
mydict = {id: num, cityid: loc, days: tem}
```

3 - Rewrite csv file, first writing *rows[0]*, followed by *header_dict* keys, followed by the remaining *rows*

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    a = csv.writer(f)
    a.writerow(rows[0])
    a.writerow([mydict[key] for key in rows[0]])
    a.writerows(rows[1:])
```

Comment: where are u reading the mydict?

Comment: See edits - this assumes the keys from your dictionary are the first row of your .csv. You'll have to update for your application.

Comment: It inserts a blank line after each row and please see my edits in the question

Comment: Think about what the code is doing - we read the .csv, use the first row as our header, I created a header dictionary using arbitrary values, and re-wrote the .csv. If you get rid of header_dict and replace it with mydict - assuming mydict is defined, it should work.

Comment: Yeah I understood but i am not able to remove the empty row after every row. Could you suggest me?

Comment: It gives me a Key error because  row starts with data rather than with column names therefore it is not able to match and gives me a key error. is there any way to solve this?